# I am getting the syntax error in the line mentioned

Tags: syntax

```java
package conditionalStatements;

public class NestedIfElse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int a = 12, b = 80 ,c = 50;
        
        int result = 0;
        
        if(a>b) {
            if (a>c) {
                result = a;
                
            } else {
                result = c;
            }
        } else {
                    if(b>c);{
                        result = b;
                        
                        else {                     i am getting syntax error in this line 
                        
                        result = c;
                    }   
                    }
                    }
                System.out.println("largest of the the three numbers is " + result);
                }
            }
```

I am getting the syntax error in the line mentioned

Comment: Please specify the language used.

Comment: i have used java

Comment: Please update your answer to the language used in the tags section.

Comment: you must tell us the precise exact literal verbatim error message. I see a stray `;`. you should also indent your code properly.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int a = 12, b = 80 ,c = 50;

int result = 0;

if(a>b) {
    if (a>c) {
        result = a;
        
    } else {
        result = c;
    }
} else {
            if(b>c);{
                result = b;
                
                else {                     i am getting syntax error in this line 
                
                    result = c;
            }   
            }
            }
        System.out.println("largest of the the three numbers is " + result);
        }
    } // copy this one
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: result = c; should be in the else

Comment: Please edit your answer so the solution is clear for the original poster.

Comment: i have copied this one but it''s showing the same error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int a = 12, b = 80 ,c = 50;

int result = 0;

if(a>b) {

    if (a>c) {
        result = a;
        
    }
    else {
        result = c;
    }
} else {
        
        if(b>c){
            result = b;
                
        }else {                    // i am getting syntax error in this line 
                
            result = c;
               
        }
}
System.out.println("largest of the the three numbers is " + result);
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer and describe why this solution works.

Comment: it''s working now

Comment: @nissimabecera your soloution is ruuning can you please tellme what was the error i was making?

Comment: The java debugger says " error: 'else' without 'if' " this error may occur when the if-else blocs aren't properly delimited with { } characters. So first, just before the else, it's missing a }, but after an instruction " result=c; ", there is 1 closing brace too much.